# Tableau LOD fixed expression with calculated field ratio

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset of Facebook posts with count of `engagements` and total `reach` for each post, for a list of markets and dates.

As part of the work I have defined `engagement rate` as a calculated field =  `SUM(engagements)/SUM(reach)`.

Now I want to produce a table showing for each market what is the difference in engagement rate respect to the average engagement rate of all the markets in the view (as a benchmark).

I have tried to use Fixed LOD expressions to achieve this, but I cannot make it work. The fixed value across all markets included in the filter does not correspond to the average of all the markets in the view. It's not even the sum of the market engagement rates, it's a number that I have no idea where is coming from.

To test the Fixed LOD expressions I tried using it with the row  `engagements` metric (as well as `reach` and `Number of Records`) and the Fixed LOD expressions returns the sum of the engagements for all markets, as expected.

I'm not sure how to get the average of the markets average engagement rates. Unfortunately I cannot share the data as it is client sensitive.

This is the test LOD that works as expected:

`{FIXED [Emea+Emea_Importers], [Platform], [Categories EMEA Brief], [Date in range]: SUM([Engagements])}`

while this one is the one that I need, but that unfortunately doesn't work:

`{FIXED [Emea+Emea_Importers], [Platform], [Categories EMEA Brief], [Date in range]: SUM([Engagements])/SUM([Reach])}`

I have also tried the below, based on [this answer](https://community.tableau.com/thread/224293)

`{FIXED  : AVG( {FIXED [Emea+Emea_Importers], [Platform], [Categories EMEA Brief], [Date in range]: SUM([Engagements])/SUM([Reach])})}`

but again the result is not correct.

If anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: `FIXED` expressions ignore non-contextual filters, could this be what's getting you?

Comment: try putting all filters in context or you can use window_average function instead of fixed

Answer (score 1):

What you are going to want to do is create an engagement rate calculation for each market like:

```
SUM({ INCLUDE [MarketName]: SUM(Engagement) / SUM(Reach) })
```

To get the get the overall average you can use a LOD such as:

```
SUM({ EXCLUDE MarketName: SUM(Engagement) / SUM(Reach) })
```

Then you should be able to create separate calculations for the difference, like:

```
[Engagement Rate - Market Excluded] - [Engagement Rate - Market Included]
```

Your table will end up looking like this:

[image]

I used the Sample SuperStore data for the example above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your help. I have 23 Markets, do you mean I need to create 23 different calculated fields????

Comment: Of course not that would be crazy, haha. Thanks for pushing me to think smarter about the scalability of that option. I updated my response.